# ".gz" extraction problem via VBA Shell and 7z command line

Tags: vba, gzip, 7zip

I'm trying to create a function that returns unpacked file. It's only 1 file in archive. The problem comes with an unpacking part. I'm trying to get unpacked archive to the same folder as archive. `Shell` returns different not 0 values. The name seems not to be too long: `Len( myFullPath )` = 101. The file name is - `VZN_2022.csv.gz` (packed file name)

I do not see a result of unpacking: there are no unpacked file in the folder. I use the code below:

```vb
Function Foo (ByVal myFullPath as String) as Boolean ' myFullPath = folder path + "\" + filename
    Call unpackeFile( CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(myFullPath) )
End Function

Function unpackeFile(ByRef archive As Object) As Object
    ....
    commandStr = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe e " & archive.Path
    Call Shell(commandStr, 0)
    ....
End function
```

Debug.Print commandStr

C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe e \\av-fs01.av.local\profiles$\meltek\Desktop\VZN_2022.csv.gz

[image]

Comment: `Debug.? commandStr`

Comment: @GSerg `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe e \\av-fs01.av.local\profiles$\meltek\Desktop\VZN_2022.csv.gz`

Comment: You are showing us the path to your 7zip executable. Instead what is in `\\av-fs01.av.local\profiles$\meltek\Desktop\VZN_2022.csv.gz`? What happens when you use 7zip on the command line to do this manually?

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe" e "\\av-fs01.av.local\profiles$\meltek\Desktop\VZN_2022.csv.gz"`?

Comment: @GSerg thank you for the reply. Now I get `Err.Number = 53    Err.Description = File not found`. Have no idea how it can be as the filename comes with `archive.Path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the path to the executable in quotation marks too, because it has a space in it - otherwise Shell will read up to the first space (i.e., `C:\Program`)and assume the rest are arguments:

```
Function unpackeFile(ByRef archive As Object) As Object
    ....
    commandStr = Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe" & Chr(34) & " e " & Chr(34) & archive.Path & Chr(34) 
    Call Shell(commandStr, 0)
    ....
End function
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll check it on monday and come back with a feedback/

Comment: I got `Err.Number = 53    Err.Description = File not found`. Do you have an idea how to fix it ? The filename comes with archive.Path...

Comment: Then perhaps the archive path has the same issue? I have updated my  reply above to wrap the archive path in quotation marks too.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. What do you mean by ` the archive path has the same issue`?

Comment: I queried whether 'perhaps' it was the reason. What I mean is - at the command line, arguments are separated by spaces (e.g: `Copy D:\TEMP\TheFilex.XLSX C:\TEMP\`), so if you don't wrap the file path in quotation marks, the system won't know what you're referring to. Given that particular error, it's clear that one of things you're referencing is not where you say it is - Try using the command line instructions at the command line yourself to see if it works.